# yum erase tells me pkg not installed. yum install tells me package is already installed

Tags: linux, yum, rpm

Erase complains package is not installed :

```
yum erase libstdc++-4.1.2-52.el5_8.1.x86_64
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: libstdc++-4.1.2-52.el5_8.1.x86_64
Package(s) libstdc++-4.1.2-52.el5_8.1.x86_64 available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

Install complains package is already installed:

```
yum install libstdc++-4.1.2-52.el5_8.1.x86_64
Setting up Install Process
Package matching libstdc++-4.1.2-52.el5_8.1.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do
```

Why is this?

EDIT:

```
rpm -q libstdc++
libstdc++-4.1.2-54.el5
libstdc++-4.1.2-54.el5

rpm -ql libstdc++
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8

yum erase libstdc++-4.1.2-52.el5_8.1.x86_64 -d 10
Config time: 0.021
Yum Version: 3.2.22
COMMAND: yum erase libstdc++-4.1.2-52.el5_8.1.x86_64 -d 10
Installroot: /
Ext Commands:

   libstdc++-4.1.2-52.el5_8.1.x86_64
Reading Local RPMDB
rpmdb time: 0.000
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: libstdc++-4.1.2-52.el5_8.1.x86_64
Setting up Package Sacks
pkgsack time: 0.015
Package(s) libstdc++-4.1.2-52.el5_8.1.x86_64 available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

Comment: Could you run those commands with `-d 3` (`yum -d 3 ...`) and update the question? Also what does `rpm -q 'libstdc++'` say?

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: Not sure if this is going to work on CentOS 5, but could you also run `yum check`?

Answer (score 1):

You have a better version of the package than the one you want to install (`libstdc++-4.1.2-52.el5_8.1.x86_64` vs `libstdc++-4.1.2-54.el5`). When you type `yum erase libstdc++-4.1.2-52.el5_8.1.x86_64`, yum tries to erase this specific version, but it's not installed. When you type, `yum install libstdc++-4.1.2-52.el5_8.1.x86_64`, yum sees that a more recent version is already installed, so it does nothing.

If you know what you're doing and really want this specific version, use `yum downgrade`.